# JavaScript Search/Filter algorithm using includes

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, web, filter

**Background**

I'm trying to develop a search/filter algorithm with javascript, and I'm stumped. I have an array of degrees that have the degree name along with filters associated with it. My filterSearch() function gets the filters that that the user chose from the HTML fields. The getDept() function returns only one department value while the getSearchValue() returns the values from multiple-selection fields.

The filterSearch() function gets the filters that the user chose and compares it against the filters in the degrees array using the includes method. The two for loops in that function does the comparison and breaks out of the loop if there happens to be a filter that isn't a part of what the user chose. If check is still true, it is pushed onto the results array to be outputted to the user.

**The Problem**

Say I choose "Bachelor, Business, Traditional, and Main_Campus" as the user's filters, it pushes the first degree onto the results with no problem and filters out the second degree. However! Say I choose "Bachelor, Associate, Business, Traditional, and Main_Campus" I would like the second degree to be added to the results as well, but both don't get pushed. I did some debugging and it turns out that it says "Bachelor" isn't included in the first degree and "Associate" isn't in the second degree.

I'm open to all suggestions and solutions, I'd love some guidance.

```
var degrees = [
    {degree: "Business Administration", filters: "Business Bachelor Traditional Main_Campus"},
    {degree: "Applied Science", filters: "Business Associate Online Main_Campus"}
    ]

function filterSearch(){
    var filters = getFilters();
    var array = [];
    var check = false;
    var results = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < degrees.length; i++){
        array = degrees[i].filters.split(' ');
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
            if (filters.includes(array[j])) { check = true; }
            else {
                check = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (check == true) results.push(degrees[i]);
    }
}

function getFilters(){
    var filters = [];
    var d = this.getDeptVal();
    var p = this.getSearchValue('#programType');
    var f = this.getSearchValue('#formatType');
    var l = this.getSearchValue('#locationType');
    filters.push(d); filters.push(p); filters.push(f); filters.push(l); 

    return filters;
}

function getDeptVal(){
    var selected = $('#departmentType option:selected').text();
    return selected;
}

function getSearchValue(searchId){
    var selected = $(searchId).val();
    var toString = selected.toString();
    return toString;
}
```

Comment: I modified my code and got it to work just as I wanted, if you want to check it out, it's on my git repo.
https://github.com/jennicar/OOP/tree/searchEngine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need such a filter:

```js
var degrees = [
    {degree: "Business Administration", filters: "Business Bachelor Traditional Main_Campus"},
    {degree: "Applied Science", filters: "Business Associate Online Main_Campus"}
    ];


function get_degrees_by_filters(_filters){
 var found=[];
 var temp_degrees=degrees.slice(0); //clone original array
 var input_filters_arr=_filters.split(' ');
 for(var key in temp_degrees){
  var degree=temp_degrees[key].degrees;
  var filters=temp_degrees[key].filters;
  var filters_arr=filters.split(' ');
  for(var key_f in filters_arr){
   for(var key_if in input_filters_arr){
    filter=input_filters_arr[key_if];
       if(filters_arr[key_f]==filter){
         if(temp_degrees[key]){
             found.push(temp_degrees[key]);
             delete  temp_degrees[key];
         }
       }


   }
  }
 }
 return found;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="filters: Bachelor" onclick="console.log(get_degrees_by_filters('Bachelor'));"/></br>
<input type="button" value="filters: Associate" onclick="console.log(get_degrees_by_filters('Associate'));"/></br>
<input type="button" value="filters: Bachelor Associate" onclick="console.log(get_degrees_by_filters('Bachelor Associate'));"/></br>
<input type="button" value="filters: Associate Online" onclick="console.log(get_degrees_by_filters('Associate Online'));"/></br>
```